# RoR scaffold error, 'undefined method to_datetime for 0:Fixnum'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, scaffolding

I'm new on RoR and then to scaffold a table with datetime type, the following error appear when I enter to generated 'New' page form:

undefined method `to_datetime' for 0:Fixnum

```
<%= form_for(@alumno) do |f| %>
<% if @alumno.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@alumno.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this alumno from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @alumno.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :nombres %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :nombres %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :apellido_paterno %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :apellido_paterno %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :apellido_materno %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :apellido_materno %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :dni %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :dni %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :usuario %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :usuario %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :usuario_personal %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :usuario_personal %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :pass %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :pass %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :fecha_registro %><br>
  <%= f.datetime_select :fecha_registro %> /*error happens here*/
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :fecha_modificacion %><br>
  <%= f.datetime_select :fecha_modificacion %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

I found similar questions but don't know exactly how repair the issue.
RoR version 4.0.0

ruby version 2.3.1p112

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't show where the error is occurring, but the bottom line is that you're trying to call `to_datetime` on an integer value. `to_datetime`, however, is a [member of String](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime), not integer. Whatever you're trying to convert into a `DateTime` object must be a String.

If you post the code where the error actually occurs, I can give you more specific direction, but what I've posted so far should be enough to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: According to your request I add a mark for that, but i think that its obvious :P.

Comment: You should take a look at what you posted. I don't see any call to the `to_datetime` method, so I hardly think it's obvious.

Comment: I thought that is obvious because I am using (i think so) a formbuilder helper, and its a trivial crud, so there are just two places in code where I am using datetime values, whatever I am confuse like you because i dont know where im using to_datetime method... , sorry is sound rude and thank you for help.